# Let $R=M_n(D)$, $D$ is a division ring. Prove that every $R-$simple module is isomorphic to each other.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R=M_n(D)$, $D$ is a division ring. Prove that every $R-$simple module is isomorphic to each other.

I need some hints to prove it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: First of all, can you think of a simple $R$-module?

Answer (score 4):

One way to approach the problem: If $M$ is a simple $R$-module, then $M \cong R/I$ for some maximal left ideal $I ⊂ R$. What are the maximal left ideals in $R$?

Elaborating: Show that a maximal left ideal $I ⊂ R $ is already generated by any matrix of maximal rank in $I$ and find that maximal rank. *Hint*: Use row reduction. Then show that any two matrices with this rank differ¹ by an $R$-module automorphism $R → R$. *Hint*: Use column reduction.

What can you conclude about any two maximal left ideals in $R$? You can use the first isomorphism theorem for the final step.

¹: They might also differ by some unit of $R$ as well.

Comment: This is true, but it only translates the problem to "Show the set of quotients of the form $R/I$ for maximal left ideals $I$ of $R$ are all mutually isomorphic," so the major part of the problem is still up in the air...

Comment: @rschwieb: It translates to showing that for any two left ideals $I$ and $J$ of $R$, there’s an $R$-automorphism $R → R$ sending $I$ to $J$. This is easily shown, those morphisms are column permutations.

Comment: Yes, they're certainly isomorphic and then you can certainly use that to help show the quotients are isomorphic, but that's still a very big jump. The last claim is just incorrect: $\{[\begin{smallmatrix}a&0\\b&0\end{smallmatrix}]\mid a,b\in R\}$ and $\{[\begin{smallmatrix}a&a\\b&b\end{smallmatrix}]\mid a,b\in R\}$ are both maximal left ideals, and no column permutation will produce an isomorphism... Even more to the point, there are only finitely many permutations, and yet there are infinitely many maximal left ideals if $D$ is infinite.

Comment: @rschwieb Oh, I didn’t think of that. So I was wrong – I will edit the answer in the near future (or maybe delete it).

Comment: No problem. Sorry, I don't mean to be [Debbie Downer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debbie_Downer) about anything. I just thought (and still think) with another line you might make a really good hint.

Comment: @rschwieb: I updated the answer and feel pretty certain that the now suggested argument works out. Let me know if you find any other mistakes/gaps. Otherwise, please undownvote.